# What is the intuition behind the ${\nabla u^T}$ term of the stress/strain tensor for a Newtonian fluid?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, tensor-calculus, stress-strain

$$\epsilon=\frac{\nabla u+ \nabla u^T}{2},$$

$u$ is vector displacement, and $\nabla u$ is the gradient matrix of $u$.

Now for a Newtonian, incompressible fluid, this describes the shear stress forces on a surface element. the problem is, I can see why $\nabla u$ is needed, the gradient in velocity of the direction parallel to the force creates a drag force on surface element due to viscosity.

But why is ${\nabla u^T}$ needed? As far as i can tell there is no physical intuition for this term?

Comment: the tensor $\epsilon$ is symmetrical

Comment: I am aware. but this is ad hoc from  angular momentum. and does not give any physical intuition to the second term regarding forces and shear

Comment: one man's *ad hoc* is another man's *propter hoc*...

Comment: how does a sideways velocity gradient for upwards velocity, through a surface element with normal vector upwards, pull the element sideways?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Viscous stress tensor for an incompressible Newtonian fluid](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/717390/viscous-stress-tensor-for-an-incompressible-newtonian-fluid)

Comment: Why is there a NORMAL strain?

Comment: it makes sense when you actually think about velocity gradients as making the element try to 'twist' (which is the case), in this case, both terms have the same effect on the element